# No deduction in a class template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T> 
class A { 
  public: 
    A(T b) : a(b) { 
    } 
  private: 
    T a; 
}; 

A object(12); //Why does it give an error?
```

Why can't the type T be deduced from the argument `12` automatically?

Comment: @litb: but if nobody can find the original, then it's probably a good idea to give search engines a second bite of the cherry.

Answer (score 4):

[Template argument deduction](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/template_argument_deduction.htm) applies only to function and member function templates but not to class templates. So your code is ill-formed.

You need to provide the template argument explicitly.

```
A<int> object(12); //fine
```

Comment: Please note that it is likely that template argument deduction for class templates will be included in in C++17: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html